# Java LONG integer types

Tags: java

Are you required to define a `Long` variable as

`Long myUserId = 1L;` ?

How come you can't just do `Long myUserId = 1;` ?

Comment: Well you answered your first question yourself.

Comment: I would guess that you could assign "1" (or any "int" valued compile time expression) and the compiler would do a cast to do the assignment.

Comment: @IraBaxter: It will do a widening cast (for int to long), but not an autoboxing after that.

Comment: Checkout the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769963/javas-l-number-long-specification-question.. It has the explaination.

Comment: @Thilo: I missed the "Long" vs. "long".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Long myUserId = 1;   // error
```

does not work, because `1` is an int.

It will get auto-boxed to:

```
Integer myUserId = 1;   // ok
```

It will also get widened to:

```
long myUserId = 1;      // also ok
```

but not both.

So, yes, you have to say

```
Long myUserId = 1L;
```

which is a `long` that can get autoboxed into a `Long`.

As to why it works that way (or rather does not work in this case): Most likely because auto-boxing was added later (in Java5), and had to be absolutely backwards-compatible. That limited how "smooth" they could make it.

Answer (score 1):

Because otherwise, Java defaults all numeric types to an Integer.

The only reason "1L" is even allowed to be assigned to a `Long` (instead of the primitive `long`) is due to the "auto-boxing" introduced with Java 5.

Without the "1L", behind-the-scenes, this looks like the following without the "L":

```
Long myUserId = Integer.valueOf(1);
```

... which I hope obviously explains itself.  :-)