# Java mistaking primitive data types?

Tags: java, types, primitive

Problem: I can't store the number '600851475143'. I realize this number is bigger than what an int can hold and is smaller than the maximum long value. However, my program isn't registering the variable "number" as a long, it is registering it as a int. Can someone shed some light onto this problem?

** - Line of the problem

```
public class Problem3{
//What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143
public static void main(String[] args){
  ***long number = 600851475143 , total = 0;
    for(long x = (number-1)/2; x>1; x--)
      if(number%x == 0 && isPrime(x)) total += x;
    System.out.println(total);
}
private static boolean isPrime(long determine){
  for(long x = determine/2 - 1; x>1; x--)
    if(determine%x ==0) return false;
  return true;
}
```

}

SOLUTION: As Jim said below, in order to of type long, one has to put a  "L" or "l" at the end of the number. 
"An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l; otherwise it is of type int. It is recommended that you use the upper case letter L because the lower case letter l is hard to distinguish from the digit 1." - From Oracle site on Primitive types.

A little more info:
[Java's L number (long) specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769963/javas-l-number-long-specification-question)

Comment: I see 2147483647 in your code, not 600851475143. Not that that should cause `number` to be an int and not a long...

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to solve my issue. The "2147483647" is the max number that can be stored as an int. I realized that any number above this number was causing an error. I edited my original post to avoid potential confusion for people in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Long literals need to be expressed with a trailing "L", as in `600851475143L`

Comment: Thank you Jim. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Put a small 'L' in this literal value:

```
 600851475143L
```

The reason is:

An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l; otherwise it is of type int. It is recommended that you use the upper case letter L because the lower case letter l is hard to distinguish from the digit 1.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

You can use this notation too, to be more clear:

```
 600_851_475_143L
```

Comment: Doesn't have to be a small 'l', it can be a big L too.

Comment: I recommend against using lowercase L, since it often looks like a 1 (one). Instead, use uppercase L.

Comment: Yes, sometimes is hard to distinguish l from 1. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> "my program isn't registering the variable "number" as a long, it is
>   registering it as a int".

That's not correct. You declared it as a long. It's a long.

What you must be getting is something quite different: a *compile error* on the constant 600851475143. Try 600851475143L. I suggest that if you read the compiler error message more carefully you would have seen that.

Comment: Thank you, I did further research after. My compiler only said "Error: integer number too large: 6008514751143".

Comment: @user1390463 Exactly as I said. The compiler has told you exactly what is wrong. Your first mistake was to mangle what the message told you into "isn't registering the variable "number" as a long".