# Avoiding Overflow

Tags: scala, long-integer

This Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769963/javas-l-number-long-specification) discusses the potential problem of a numeric overflow if not appending `L` to a number:

Here's an example from the REPL:

```
scala> 100000 * 100000 // no type specified, so numbers are `int`'s
res0: Int = 1410065408
```

One way to avoid this problem is to use `L`.

```
scala> 100000L * 100000L
res1: Long = 10000000000
```

Or to specify the number's types:

```
scala> val x: Long = 100000
x: Long = 100000

scala> x * x
res2: Long = 10000000000
```

What's considered the best practice to properly specify a number's type?

Comment: This is really an opinion question. There is no universally accepted best practice for this. I'd just use the `L` suffix.

Comment: This isn't a matter of opinion. Adding an `L` specifies the right type, using ascription converts it afterwards.

Comment: In light of Daniel's comment, why am I getting down-votes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should *always* use `L` if you are using a long. Otherwise, you can still have problems:

```
scala> val x: Long = 10000000000
<console>:1: error: integer number too large
       val x: Long = 10000000000
                     ^

scala> val x = 10000000000L
x: Long = 10000000000
```

The conversion due to type ascription happens after the literal has been interpreted as `Int`.

Comment: Why doesn't `100000 * 100000` get stored in a data structure that can hold the value *without* overflowing? Is it a high burden on the programming language writer?

Comment: @KevinMeredith In some languages, it does. Scala follows Java convention and types, which was inherited from C by way of C++, and defaults to numeric types that can be efficiently manipulated by the CPU -- with direct translations into machine code, often enough.