# Java virtual function calls

Tags: java, function, virtual

From my understanding all function-calls in Java are virtual, and numeral literals have the type int. But why does the Output in the example below differ?

```
public class A {
    public int f(long d) {
        return 2;
    }
}
public class B extends A {
    public int f(int d) {
        return 1;
    }
}
public class M {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        A ab = b;
        System.out.println(b.f(1));
        System.out.println(ab.f(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: `A` doesn't define any `f(int)` method, so obviously, `f(long)` is called in the second case. There is no method overriding in your code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont override anything.

- The first calling `System.out.println(b.f(1));` returns `1`, because it works with `class B`, even the method is named same, but parameters are different (`long` is not the same as `int`).
- In case when parameters are same `(int d)`, the result would be `1`, because it overrides (`@Override`) the method from the `class A`.
- Now, you know why the second calling `System.out.println(ab.f(1));` returns `2`. Look from what class it's called from.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the subclass B has inherited the method f(with a long) and has added (overloaded) another method f(with a int).
When you write down a value such as 1 in such a way the compiler, even before assigning it to a typed reference does parse it as an int. More here: [Java's L number (long) specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769963/javas-l-number-long-specification) .

When you call the method f using the reference ab (which is A class) it (the reference) says I can only send you to a method f(with a long) and then implicitly cast the type int 1 into a long.

Let's try to change the type of the method in A class to f(short),
then System.out.println(ab.f(1)); will give you this error:
"The method f(short) in the type A is not applicable for the arguments (int)"