# Why is a long written with an L

Tags: java, variables, types, declaration

If I want to save a long variable, why do I have to write an `L` or `l` at the end of the value?

For example:

```
9_223_372
long v = 9_223_372L;
```

But if I save it:

```
long v = 9_223_372;
```

it's still a long variable. So why do I have to write L or l?

Comment: `long v = 9_223_372_036_854_775;` Have you even tried running this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769963/javas-l-number-long-specification

Comment: The postfix `L`is needed for `long` numbers that are above the range of an `int`.

On a side note: Is is preferrable to use `L` instead of `l`, because `l` can easily get misread as `1` for most fonts.

Comment: For long numbers outside the int range, 999999999999L, and for contexts that can have both int and long - seldom

Comment: @DorianGray, for that same reason you'll also see `d` preferred to `D` when working with doubles.

Comment: @Dorian Gray I reckon you answered your own question. Clarity is king and so where permitted L.

Comment: @TJA What do you mean woth " I reckon you answered your own question." ? I didn't ask a question.

Comment: It is for the benefit of the compiler so it knows whether the literal should be an int or a long.

Comment: @Dorian Gray sorry was tired and misread your statement.

Answer (score 1):

### `int` literal

If you do not write it, Java will create it as `int` and from there cast to `long`:

```
long number = 10;
// Is the same as
long number = (long) 10;
// i.e.
int asInt = 10;
long number = (long) asInt;
```

This works as long as the number you are writing is an `int` and will fail if its not, for example a very high number:

```
// Fails, "integer number too large"
long number = 10_000_000_000_000_000;
```

With `L` (or `l`) you tell Java that this literal is a `long` and not an `int` in the first place. Which also gets rid of the unnecessary conversion:

```
long number = 10_000_000_000_000_000L;
```

---

### Note

The same also works for floating numbers, when you want a `float` instead of a `double`, you add `F` (or `f`). Technically, you can also add `D` or `d` for a `double`, but a floating number literal is already `double` by default, so this is not needed:

```
float asFloat = 0.5F;
double asDouble = 0.5D;
double alreadyDoubleByDefault = 0.5;
```

By the way, please do not use `l` (small `L`), it gets easily confused with `1` (one).